# Average completed events per day (in Month)

Tags: sql, sql-server

Using SQL, how do I count Average completed events per day in Month?

sample data:

```
ID  Fullname    Events  Status  DateContacted   UserID
1   Jack    Phone Call  Completed   2017-03-10 00:00:00.000 14587bg   
2   Dawn    Meeting Completed   2017-03-08 00:00:00.000 15879uj   
3   Helen   Phone Call  NULL    2017-02-02 00:00:00.000 89751po   
4   Sam Appointment Completed   2017-02-10 00:00:00.000 35784ly   
5   David   Skype   Completed   2017-01-01 00:00:00.000 3337jy    
6   Jack    Skype   Completed   2017-01-14 00:00:00.000 14587bg
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Count the number of events completed and count the number of days in the month.  Let me assume that you don't care about days with no events.

```
select year(datecontacted) as yyyy, month(datecontacted) as mm,
       (sum(case when status = 'Completed' then 1.0 else 0 end) / 
        count(distinct cast(datecontact as date))
       ) as avg_completed_per_day
from sample s
group by year(datecontacted), month(datecontacted)
order by yyyy, mm;
```

Comment: Hi Gordon, wow! that was quick!  It looks like what I want, I'm just checking it through, and fine tuning.  I will get back to you

Comment: Hi Gordon, seems to be counting rather than giving average.  I added in total 7 completed events in one day for name Laura, and your query gives 7 as average, I expected it to be less.  ID Fullname CallType Status DateContacted UserID
2 Laura Meeting Completed 2017-03-08 00:00:00.000 15879uj

Comment: @Peppe . . . I don't see what "Laura" has to do with this question.  If you have a different question you should ask *another* question, with sample data and desired results.

Comment: Hi Gordon, yes the name Laura is not in that dataset, sorry for the confusion. Simply, what I'm saying is that your query does a great job of counting number of completed events, but it does not give the average of completed events. Would you mind checking your query. It is the same question I initially asked. Thank you for your support, Appreciated!

Comment: Hi Gordon.  I double checked the data, and confirm that your is giving the right results.  Thank you!  Can you also show me how I do it for per day in Quarter, and also per day in year Year?  Thanks for your support!

Comment: @Peppe . . . Questions should be asked as *questions* and not in *comments*.  If you have a follow-on question, then ask it as a new *question*.

Comment: I had to do it via the comments as I still can't figure out where you ask the question.  When I first signed up I was able to ask a question, but now I can't find where on the stackflow site to ask a question? You answered my first question correctly, and I worked out how to do it for month, quarter and year for completed events per day.  Now I want to know how to do it per week for month, quarter, year?